# Saving a RotateImage

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

Using this freeware to update some D5-ent stuff for my local gardening club database.

http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/rotateimage/

It has a LoadFromFile, is fast enough and works very well, but it has no SaveToFile. The forum on the site has some very old questions asked about the Saving, but no definitive answers.

Could someone please show me how to go about saving the image once it has been rotated?

I have found a bunch of routines online for image saving and none of them seem to work. It saves something but it is no longer a JPG. I tried looking for a way of saving the Canvas but could not get anything to compile. Generally they all broke down with "Cannot assign a Bitmap/Canvas,Picture/etc to a TRotateImage"

A little out of my depth here.

p.s. Tried ImageEx and Image32 but both versions for D5 are way too complicated to use just to save the rotated file.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation of `TRotateImage`, it has a property called `RotatedBitmap` which stores the rotated image as bitmap. You can easily convert that bitmap to a JPEG image using the `TJPEGImage` class from the unit `jpeg`:

```
uses jpeg;

procedure SaveRotatedImage;
var
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  jpg := TJPEGImage.Create();
  try
    jpg.Assign(YourRotateImage.RotatedBitmap);
    jpg.SaveToFile('filename.jpg');
  finally
    jpg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As an alternative to `TRotateImage`, I recommend the [`Graphics32`](http://graphics32.org/) library which can apply more complex transformations to images using various interpolation kernels, handle transparency and much more. But if you just need rotation and are satisfied with the results of your component, you may as well stay with it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that later today. I had installed graphics32 but it has big learning curve and I don't want to have to do a major rewrite to this old application.